# Conditional execution not working for this case of code?

Tags: c

Why the code inside the `#ifdef INITIALISATION` and `#endif` is not executed?

```
int main(void)
    {
       uint8_t  DLEVEL = 10; 
       #if DLEVEL > 5
        #define INITIALISATION
       #endif
       while (1)
       {
          #ifdef INITIALISATION
             Display();      // This line is never being executing :: please help for a solution
          #endif
       }
    }
```

edited...

Thanks for the reply

Actually the below mentioned logic of the code is used as a part of my code memory optimization.
Now the code memory size is overflowed, so i need to execute the one time initializations when the `SYM_DLEVEL` value is `10` and then the value of `SYM_DLEVEL` is changed from `10 to 2`, then the initial sections i need to be **automatically commented or disabled** and then only the `Display_2()` function needed to be **enable and need to execute**.
Is it possible?

```
#define SYM_DLEVEL 10
int main(void)
    {
       #if SYM_DLEVEL > 5
        Display_1();             // need to execute this line once(before the value changes from 10 t0 2)
       #endif
       
       #define SYM_DLEVEL 2      // after this line execution i need to automatically disable the above section and automatically enable the below section
       #if SYM_DLEVEL < 5
        #define INITIALISATION   // need to execute only when value changes from 10 to 2
       #endif
       while (1)
       {
          #ifdef INITIALISATION
             Display_2();        
          #endif
       }
    }
```

Comment: DLEVEL is not a preprocessor constant. It is a variable.

Comment: That's _conditional compilation_ not conditional execution.  There in lies your misunderstanding. The undefined implied macro `DLEVEL` is not the same thing as the variable `DLEVEL`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't execute code because the preprocessor runs in the compiler, while the local variable DLEVEL is assigned during execution.
The preprocessor simply looks for **a preprocessor symbol `DLEVEL`** that evidently is undefined.
Undefined symbols are equated to 0, so the symbol `INITIALISATION` isn't defined.

To make it work define a preprocessor symbol, i.e. `SYM_DLEVEL`, to be used in the conditional preprocessing, and eventually assign it to the runtime variable. I.e.

```
#define SYM_DLEVEL 10
int main(void)
    {
       uint8_t  DLEVEL = SYM_DLEVEL; 
       #if SYM_DLEVEL > 5
        #define INITIALISATION
       #endif
       while (1)
       {
          #ifdef INITIALISATION
             Display();      // This line is now is executed
          #endif
       }
    }
```

Remember that preprocessing is more or less a text processor (which actuates on base piece of text, tokens, as outlined in comments below), and is executed before the compilation of the code. It doesn't know about runtime variables and their assignments, it only knows symbols defined with a preprocessor directive (`#define`).

Don't confuse actions as **dead code removal** or other **optimization** made by compiler with what the preprocessor can do. The golden rule is: "preprocessing only understand preprocessing objects, C code is a plain text without any special meaning for it".

Comment: Re “preprocessing is simply a text replacement”: It is actually preprocessor token replacement, which is different. For example, `#define x +` will not cause `x+` to become the token `++`; it will result in two separate `+` tokens.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks Erich. I used a simplified definition of course the details are more complex. I'll review the answer.